# Use medieval (lowercase, non-lining) numbers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, nsattributedstring, typography

I have a request from a customer to use a certain font in a iOS 7 project because it has [medieval numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures).

Is there any way to activate those numbers for a NSAttributedString? As default lining numbers are used, that are included in the font as-well.

---

Here is an example. Both lines have the same font with no variant (Regular), once with medieval numbers activated, the second wit the default lining numbers.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by activate? Doesn't changing the font work?

Comment: The font has 2 number styles. The lining-style is the default one. @Sulthan

Comment: @Sulthan, maybe the image I added will make things clearer.

Comment: outstanding information about "ranging" "medieval" numbers, thanks!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are called **lowercase numbers** and can be turned on using `UIFontDescriptor`.

First, you need to import CoreText for some constants:

```
#import <CoreText/SFNTLayoutTypes.h>
or
@import CoreText.SFNTLayoutTypes;
```

Then create font using font descriptor. Here I use *Georgia* family:

```
NSDictionary *lowercaseNumbers = @{
                                   UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kNumberCaseType),
                                   UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @(kLowerCaseNumbersSelector),
                                   };
UIFontDescriptor *descriptor = [[UIFontDescriptor alloc] initWithFontAttributes:
                                @{
                                  UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute: @"Georgia",
                                  UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute:@[ lowercaseNumbers ],
                                  }];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:descriptor size:15];
```

Result:
[image]

**Edit:** As *@Random832* pointed out, *Georgia* has only lowercase numbers, so the result is irrelevant. However, *@vikingosegundo* confirmed this code works on supported fonts. Thanks.

[image]

The top line was generated with

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN Next LT Pro" size:12];
if (font)
    label.font = font;
```

the second line with

```
NSDictionary *lowercaseNumbers = @{  UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey:@(kNumberCaseType), UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @(kLowerCaseNumbersSelector)};
UIFontDescriptor *descriptor = [[UIFontDescriptor alloc] initWithFontAttributes:
                                @{UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute: @"DIN Next LT Pro",UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute:@[ lowercaseNumbers ]}];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:descriptor size:12];
if (font)
    label.font = font;
```

Comment: No problem. It's worth looking into _SFNTLayoutTypes.h_, you may find some more interesting features, like proportional numbers or alternative punctuation.

Comment: I guess the biggest problem is the wording. Typography has so many Vocabulary I don't know. even in my own mother language.

Comment: @vikingosegundo In that case, you have to try all of them to see what they do ;)

Comment: Georgia has lowercase numbers by default and I'm not sure if it has uppercase numbers, maybe an example with a different font for the example?

Comment: @Random832: I use DIN Next LT Regular. It is not freely available. But it has both - non-lining and lining numerals. And iMartins code is working with it.

Comment: @Random832 Ouch, you are right :D I will try to finding one that has both.

Comment: I found both _Didot_ and _Marion_ to have lowercase numbers on OS X, but none of them are present on iOS. Please, @vikingosegundo, could you edit my answer by providing screenshots of your font? :)

Comment: @iMartin: with pleasure

Answer (score 2):

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745002/accessing-opentype-features-in-uikit-or-coretext) has a pointer in the right direction, though the question mentions tabular figures [vs proportional] rather than text vs lining.

It looks like you can use [CTFontDescriptorCreateCopyWithFeature](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontDescriptorRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontDescriptorCreateCopyWithFeature) with `kNumberCaseType` set to `kLowerCaseNumbersSelector` to display the digits this way.

[Here's another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663661/turning-numbers-into-uppercase-numbers-with-nsattributedstring-nsstring-and-uila), and [here's the blog post provided in the answer](http://blog.amyworrall.com/post/46329875785/core-text-and-upper-case-numbers).